# Replicate 2 ubuntu Servers one local and one remote

Tags: webserver

Here is the situation.

I have a local webserver and a remote webserver.
Both will be identical except that one is on **VMware** and one is a hosted web server.

I want to replicate EVERYTHING installed on the local server (settings, applications- mysql, apache, the cron jobs, and all the data and files - php) to be on the live hosted web server. So that everything is identical and functions exactly the same.

I know I will probably have to do some changes of setting once it is live, for it to run correctly, but **is there an easy and relatively fast way to do this?**

I am new at this and never done this before.

**Will I have to setup the server from scratch** or **can I clone or copy everything to the new server?**

Comment: I guess thinking about this it would be similar to a server migration but I have never done one before.

Comment: I think this post might help... but I am note sure: 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/246064/script-tool-to-clone-a-ubuntu-server?rq=1