# Question about cloning

Tags: cloning

It is my third time installing Ubuntu 16.04 on Linux because what I am trying to do is create a webserver for internet and intranet users, and because I am new, messing around with settings opens up a can of worms for me, and I have to reinstall everything. Although fun and I am learning, it is time consuming. I don't want to do that all the time.

So my question is about cloning. What is it? If it is what I think it is, which is to copy exactly the same state as a hardrive or a partition, restore to a good copy then where do I start? Any good software to help? What problems will I encounter?

Comment: Sorry, adding more information. My Ubuntu install is server 16.04 dual boot with Windows 8 host. I forsee start up problems with cloning so let me know what I can do to minumize that.

Comment: On a partiton and on the same HD

Comment: Try checking out these posts: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/246064/script-tool-to-clone-a-ubuntu-server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/245406/how-to-make-a-home-server-using-ubuntu-desktop) http://askubuntu.com/questions/245406/how-to-make-a-home-server-using-ubuntu-desktop    ... Let me know if this helped.

Comment: The answer you're looking for is in here I believe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/245406/how-to-make-a-home-server-using-ubuntu-desktop AND http://askubuntu.com/questions/246064/script-tool-to-clone-a-ubuntu-server

Comment: You might also want to look into snapshots, if you have a known good state you can take a snapshot before starting your experiment and then restore that snapshot afterwards if necessary.